# POSTing data to webAPI from method in ASP.Net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am finding a lot of sites that will tell me how to write a webAPI and consume data or how to use jQuery to POST to an API but I have not been able to find out how to post data to an API from within an ASP.Net MVC 6 method. I figure I need to build out a JSON object then somehow pass that object to the correct URL

The API that brought this question up is https://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/5.0/api/core/v1/bug.html#create-bug

Comment: The `HttpClient` class is probably what you're looking for.  Anything that can make HTTP requests and read the responses will do the job.

Comment: It would really help if you show your API method and the code you have tried to call it with, along with the results of that and what further research you did, as all is explained in [ask]. Please read it and [edit] your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Link the API that started the question added. Should I stat linking to all the tutorials that are outdated and do not apply to ASP.Net 5 as what I have "tried" otherwise I really have no code to show.

Comment: Are you using .Net core?  The question is really not helpful.

Comment: @Cleverguy25 Yes, that is why I tagged it with both core tags. How is this not helpfull? Everything I am finding does not apply. If you need clarity on something in my question please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to use the `SendAsync` method of the `HttpClient` from `System.Net.Http`.

Answer (score -1):

Is this more what you are looking for?

http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/12/10/typed-extensions-for-httpclient-on-net-core/

Comment: Which method does it not have?

Comment: That link is not valid either, there is no `PostAsJsonAsync` in `HttpClient`

Answer (score -1):

I recently posted an answer to a similar question.  Perhaps this helps answer your question?  [Creating a JSON object in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001701/creating-a-json-object-in-asp-net-5-to-pass-to-a-rest-api/35002069#35002069)

Comment: That question is about which method I am supposed to use to create the Json. The new `Formatters.Json` or the older `NewtonSoft`. Not about how to send the object to an API.

Comment: You need to send JSON to a URL from within a method running in ASP.Net MVC 6.  The question you asked appears to be asking how you communicate with a REST service when your inside a method in MVC 6.  The answer is the same for consuming the service in a web forms app, windows forms app, wpf app, or MVC6 app.  There is no special method you need to use to communicate with a REST service from an MVC6 app.  Maybe I just don't understand the question?

Comment: That question is about how to create the JSON object and which method is best to use in a .Net 5 environment. I just noticed that I accidently put "to pass to a REST API" in the subject. The intent of that question is to make a Json object that can be passed to anything. APIs, JavaScript AJAX request, etc.