# Creating a JSON object in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a JSON object in a .Net 5 application. The default options I am presented with are `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`, and `Newtonsoft.Json` when I use the Visual Studio 2015 Qucik Actions on `Json`. My understanding is that `Configuration.Json` is for reading form the `appsettings.json` so it probably is not what I would use to create a JSON object. I can't find any real information on `Formatters.Json`, how to use it, or what it's intended use it. `Newtonsoft.Json` is will documented but is it better over the `Formatters.Json`? Which of the two should I be using?

Comment: This has been asked (and answered) many times before. In my opinion the best option (performance, features, support, etc.) is to use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Just add it to your bower file and you're set. Please note that the duplicated question is about .NET 4 but still applies to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera This is not a duplicate. .Net 4 and .Net core have different packages, two of which are new to .Net 5. Yes, Netwonsoft is for .Net 4 but the other two are not so the best method may have changed for .Net 5

Comment: Hm. Please state better your question: *I am not sure which one I am supposed to use to build a Json object* is not an a/b question, since there are many options. Have you *tried* Json.Net?

Comment: I've retracted my vote, but still think you need to elaborate a little bit better. Regarding the output formatters, what do you have in your `config.json` file?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I have re-written the question so it is hopefully easier to understand. As for the output formatters, I don't have a `config.json` file but looking at both `appsettings.json` and `project.json` I don't see anything that hints it is an output formatter.

Comment: my mistake, I meant *Startup.cs*.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera No big. I do have `UseMVC()` so what ever out putters it has is what I have.

Comment: Just to be sure here - do you want to send a JSON object back to the client or do you want to serialize it to JSON and then send it off to some other service from within asp.net 5 (regardless of where that other service lives)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken directly from [ASP.NET Core 1 tests](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8b1bd343ba56152d2a7e677cf041dc9d62b4033f/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Test/Internal/JsonResultExecutorTest.cs)

```
var expected = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { foo = "abcd" }));
```

Also taken [from the tests](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/25eb50120eceb62fd24ab5404210428fcdf0c400/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FunctionalTests/BasicTests.cs) and slightly modified, call it with HttpClient to see how to send your json string to the server.

```
var response = await Client.PostAsync(
                "http://localhost/api/ActionUsingSpecificFormatters",
                new StringContent(yourJsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

As per [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) you can simply encode, then do whatever you want after that.

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output);
```

Putting it all together - I just tested this. Keep in mind this is a real generic pass through test from MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5 ie ASP.NET Core 1)  :)

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var customer = new Customer() { Name = "Schmo", Address = "1999 Purple Rain St" };

    var customerJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(
                    "http://localhost:4815/api/Customer",
                    new StringContent(customerJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));


    //just some template output to test which I'm getting back.
    string resultJson = "{ 'Name':'adam'}";

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        resultJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var updatedCustomer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultJson);
    }


    return resultJson;
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestions does not apply as it is out of date. Your link is to a WebAPI 2 tutorial and I am not asking for WebAPI 2. In ASP.Net 5 `HttpClient` only has a `PostAsync` method not a `PostAsJsonAsync`. And I was able to find a lot of info on Netwonsoft but almost none on `Formatters.Json` so I was not sure which was better to us.

Comment: the first suggestion was calling webapi from a client - which is what it seems you are doing - your client is asp..net - no? ASP.NET 5 has json.net with it (in our of box templates) - a new version was just released specifically for it.

Comment: Yes but half your answer is still wrong. `HttpClient` no longer has `PostAsJsonAsync` so that tutorial will not work.

Comment: edited above and simplified (missed the initial asp.net 5)

Answer (score 2):

I would use Json.Net to create the JSON payloads for sure (Afterall, Microsoft does for Web Api).

Nuget Package Source:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Here is an example.  If you want to call a REST api that returns a product when you make a GET call then you might do something like this.

```
public static class Main
{
    string url = "https://TheDomainYouWantToContact.com/products/1";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();

    // This is the code that turns the JSON string into the Product object.
    Product productFromServer = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Product>(responseFromServer);
    Console.Writeline(productFromServer.Id);
}

// This is the class that represents the JSON that you want to post to the service.
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The exact same method can be used for POST and PUT as well.

You can use 3rd party assemblies to make this super easy too.  We are the authors of DynamicApis.Api

```
Install-Package DynamicApis.Api
```

The code to make the same request using this client would be:

```
public static class Main
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    string url = "https://YourDomain.com/products/1";
    var productFromServer = client.Get<Product>(url);
    Console.Writeline(productFromServer.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use NewtonSoft.Json if you need to serialize objects as json

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that one and not the `Formatters.Json`? There is not really much detail info on `Formatters.Json` so I can't compare/contrast them,

Comment: actually I was probably too hasty with my answer, under the hood Formatters.Json is using Newtonsoft.Json so I think you could use either one but probably should just use Formatters.Json unless you need to do something special

Comment: Do you have any examples of using `Formatters.Json`? I can't do a "Go To Definitions" on it and I am not getting any Intellisense on it's overload methods.

Comment: Look at the method starting at line 290 in this code from my project, I'm returning json there https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Web/Controllers/CoreDataController.cs

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to do anything special to send back Json data. The default output formatter is already Json, and if your *Startup.cs* file is somewhat normal, you should have a line similar to this:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

By default, this already contains the Json formatter, and your controller should autonegotiate the return type based on what the browser asked. So a controller like the following should work (taken from [this Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1765), which contains some information on why/how this work):

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public SomeClass Get()
    {
        return new SomeClass();
    }

    public SomeClass Post([FromBody] SomeClass x)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assuming that this Json object will always be passed to my own application and said application has an API. While your response works in that case it does not work in all cases. In this case the JSON will be either passed to an API from a third party or to a JavaScript AJAX response.

Comment: Then I'm at a loss here. Why are you asking for the Json formatter, then?

Comment: I sense that your question came with too much baggage. What do you need to *do*? Post some Json data to a third-party API? If so, then *you should be using Json.Net*.

Comment: In this particular case it will be posted to a third-party API. Is `Json.Net` and `Newtonsoft.Json` the same?

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera its not sending json back, its serializing json. Matt - Json.Net  is newtonsoft :)

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT serialization is half the equation, the other half being data transfer. Matthew, yes, they are the same.